# Android GLSurfaceView ~56fps - How to control swap?

Tags: android, opengl-es, frame-rate, vsync

When running the basic sample:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html

Add some basic timing using System.currentTimeMillis() or dropping to native code and using clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_HR, &res) both yield the same results it appears.  I tested with both separately.

I always calculate a frame rate of ~56.  That is a rough average of 18ms between frames.  I realize the timing of frames is not a perfect science (timer accuracy, device doing stuff in the background).  I simply let it run doing absolutely nothing, not even a glClear.  After an hour this is the results I got which is about the same as letting it run for 1 minutes.

I've tried many things to achieve a true 59/60fps.  I'm beginning to wonder if it is my device (HTC Incredible S).  Although I have tried Samsung Galaxy S and Nexus S both with the same results.  Tablets do not exhibit this behavior at all.  On my EEE Transformer and Xoom I get ~16ms a frame consistently.

This leads me to believe VSYNC is the issue and that the vsync on that generation of Android phones is slow.  Really VSYNC should be ~16ms.  Achieving a true 60fps is unlikely but 59fps should be common.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any tips for disabling vsync? I don't think that is possible.  Any tips for gaining control of controlling the "swap" step of rendering?

Comment: It could be a hardware limitation. But really, why are you worried about a 2ms difference?

Comment: Mostly because I'm pushing audio samples at the same time and this 2ms breaks its.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a Nexus S, frame rate is capped to 56fps.

Comment: It appears many of that generation of Android devices are like that.  Samsung Galaxy SII seems to be the start of devices which are not capped at 56fps.